# Python command to view a list with 1000 elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am using command prompt in Win 7 OS. What is the python command to view a list of 1000 items in the interpreter ?

i load the interpreter in the command prompt of win 7. so please explain keeping that in consideration.

For example:

a similar situation to view the output in linux will be:

hello.py **| more**

I want to know the python command to be used in the interpretor to view a list which contain more than 1000 items.

"   >>> l

## where l is the list

"

i meant generally the screen scrolls down at such a fast rate that the previous elements cant be viewed. so i drew an analogy that in UNIX when we have a directory containing 1000 or more files we use ( | more )  so that it halts after displaying a few elements and when we press enter the remaining are viewed

explain bit more about your problem

Comment: Can you elaborate "viewing a list of 1000 items in the interpreter"?

Comment: and that is not python cmd, It is OS cmd If I'm not wrong.!!

Answer (score 1):

The default Python REPL (the "interpreter" as you are calling it) does not do any pagination. It will happily print the entire list:

```
>>> i = range(1000)
>>> print(i)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, ... 999]
```

To get it to paginate the output, you'll have to do some extra work:

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> i = range(1000)
>>> pydoc.pager(str(i))
```

This will emulate your default pager so you can go forward and backward. Hit `q` to get back to the REPL prompt.

To print a subset of a list, use slicing:

```
>>> i[100:200]
```

If you just want to scroll up and down the output, you'll have to use an interpreter that is compatible with your windowing system; so you can use the up/down arrow keys or the mousewheel (or whatever is the "default" on your system) to scroll the output.

For Windows you can use IDLE (which comes with Python) or any other alternative REPL like ipython or bpython and then scroll the output of the window.

Comment: i meant generally the screen scrolls down at such a fast rate that the previous elements cant be viewed. so i drew an analogy that in UNIX when we have a directory containing 1000 or more files we use ( | more )  so that it halts after displaying a few elements and when we press enter the remaining are viewed

Comment: The `pydoc.pager(str(i))` will do exactly that.

Comment: but i ask for a list of 1000 elements or a dictionary
i tried "pydoc.pager(l)"  it is showing "expected string"

Comment: When you print out a list, you are printing a string representation of it. So, you need to pass that string to the pager, like this: `pydoc.pager(str(l))`

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to display 1000 items from your list. So here what you can do:

```
L[start:stop]
```

Here L is your list, start will be 0 (initial position where you want to print list data) and stop will be 999 (so that you can get 1000 elements and since array numbering starts from 0, stop parameter is 999).

Final Code: **L[0:999]**

For more information on list, you can visit [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm).
See, if that helps.